# Collectionview inside uitableview in storboard, become nil at runtime?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]i have a storyboard, with viewcontroller. Inside view controller i have a uitableview with custom cell. Inside custom cell, i have horizontal collection view , with custom collectionview cell.

when i try to access , objuitableviewcell.colllectionview inside cellforrowatIdexpath method of UITableViewDataSource , it returns nil.

Any idea why it returns nil ? i am attaching storyboard hierarchy image enter image description herefor reference.

Answer (score 0):

found answer for it, posting here so that it can be helpful to others, it was because of Inherit from target option unchecked for uitableviewcustomcell.

i have checked that option and it worked.